How to solve invalid input params issue for uniswap v2 router 'addLiquidity' method
Can you tell if I am wrong about any of the arguments used for the addLiquidity. I am using wagmi and ethers.
Error
Caused by: InvalidInputRpcError: Missing or invalid parameters.
Double check you have provided the correct parameters.

Add liquidity error ContractFunctionExecutionError: Execution reverted for an unknown reason.

Raw Call Arguments:
  from:  0x713b8F6E2e42C0481E8B2A4095A4f878BF932716
  to:    0xf9a8f24e1ff41b463761aefd17303eb2bebbb879
  data:  0xe8e33700000000000000000000000000813a68fa74acab3051be6db0552c05f622db78420000000000000000000000001009ebb7decd61f2926b19388cee335142b505b70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a764000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000152d02c7e14af68000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000dcef33a6f838000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001511e7e30a6807300000000000000000000000000000713b8f6e2e42c0481e8b2a4095a4f878bf9327160000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000066ded409
 
Contract Call:
  address:   0xf9a8f24e1ff41b463761aefd17303eb2bebbb879
  function:  addLiquidity(address tokenA, address tokenB, uint256 amountADesired, uint256 amountBDesired, uint256 amountAMin, uint256 amountBMin, address to, uint256 deadline)
  args:                  (0x813a68fa74AcAb3051Be6DB0552c05f622DB7842, 0x1009EbB7dECD61F2926b19388cEe335142b505b7, {"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0de0b6b3a7640000"}, {"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x152d02c7e14af6800000"}, {"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0dcef33a6f838000"}, {"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x1511e7e30a6807300000"}, 0x713b8F6E2e42C0481E8B2A4095A4f878BF932716, 1725879305)
  sender:    0x713b8F6E2e42C0481E8B2A4095A4f878BF932716

Here is my addLiquidity method call.
    const {
        data: hash,
        error,
        isSuccess,
        isError,
        isPending,
        writeContract,
    } = useWriteContract();
    const addLiquidity = () => {
        // 3. Add Liquidity
        writeContract({
            address: ROUTER_ADDRESS, //router address
            abi: RouterV2Abi,
            functionName: "addLiquidity",
            args: [
                tokenA, // Address of token A
                tokenB, // Address of token B
                ethers.utils.parseUnits(amountA.toString(), 18), // Amount of token A
                ethers.utils.parseUnits(amountB.toString(), 18), // Amount of token B
                ethers.utils
                    .parseUnits(amountA.toString(), 18)
                    .mul(ethers.BigNumber.from(10000 - 0.5 * 100))
                    .div(10000),
                ethers.utils
                    .parseUnits(amountB.toString(), 18)
                    .mul(ethers.BigNumber.from(10000 - 0.5 * 100))
                    .div(10000),
                account.address, // The address that will receive the liquidity tokens
                Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 1000, // Deadline (10 minutes from now)
            ],
        });
    };


Can you add the computed parameters to the question (leave out to if don't want to share that), and can you double check you aren't passing floats after division (for the slippage params).

@Maka I have added the input data. However, they are in hex format.

I checked the hex data in decimal format and they are fine

The calldata looks fine. Number of args and args. Deadline seems fine assuming it was sent before. Slippages are less than desired amounts as should be for add call. Looks good theoretically.
I cannot find that router or the tokens anywhere, is it on a fork or on a chain I can simulate against?

@Maka yes. I am forking it on https://zkscam.io/Explore testnet.
FACTORY_ADDRESS = "0x2c299728a40c93a3b4c9618de4d8779fc30ddb7f"
ROUTER_ADDRESS = "0xf9a8f24e1ff41b463761aefd17303eb2bebbb879"
What do you need more?

Ok that is helpful, but will take a bit of time to set up any potential dev env as it isn't supported by any online tooling, I had never heard of zkscam, and it's a name that begs for caution. The dev seems to be doing his own thing on a few levels, so there might be something going that your library just isn't designed to support. That explorer doesn't show any swaps, any contract code or details at the router address, is there an explorer that does? Guessing he may just not have built that in yet.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Maka can you check the discussion chat above? I put more details so you don't need a new setup
